# addEventListener on class

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I need to use `getElementsByClassName` because I have several same buttons etc. 
I work on a wordpress loop that displays a button for each new article, and a registration form must appear on each event when we click on the button.
When I click on the button, I want the form to be displayed and the button to be hidden.
Someone can help me ?

Sorry if there are mistakes, I am French.

```
var bouton = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_inscription');
var formulaire = document.getElementsByClassName('formulaire');

   var MyFonction = function{
       formulaire.style.display = 'block';
       bouton.style.display ='none';
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < bouton.length; i++) {

        bouton[i].addEventListener('click', MyFonction);
   }
```

Comment: `formoulaire` is an array. `style` does only exist on one of the arrays elements, not on the array itself. `formoulaire[0].style.display = "block"`. Also your browser did tell you that, look at the console.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, **not** an element. HTMLCollection does not have a  `style` property. **You need to iterate over the list of elements.** The DOM API is not jQuery.

Comment: @JonasWilms `formoulaire` is not an array - - it's a node list, which is an array-like object, but not an actual array. As such, it can be iterated like an array can be, but it doesn't implement the same API as arrays do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in order to pass the current index and element (rif. **this**):

```js
var bouton = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_inscription');
var formulaire = document.getElementsByClassName('formulaire');

var MyFonction = function(idx, event) {
    formulaire[idx].style.display = 'block';
    this.style.display ='none';
}

for (var i = 0; i < bouton.length; i++) {
    bouton[i].addEventListener('click', MyFonction.bind(bouton[i], i));
    //                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

```css
.formulaire {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<button class="btn_inscription">1</button>
<button class="btn_inscription">2</button>
<button class="btn_inscription">3</button>
<div class="formulaire">1</div>
<div class="formulaire">2</div>
<div class="formulaire">3</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much gaetanoM !

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` (along with `.getElementsByTagName` and `.getElementsByName`) return `node list` objects (array-like containers). You can't interact with individual element properties and methods on node lists, you have to work with objects within the container.  To set up event handlers on all the elements in the node list, you can loop through the container and set the handler one at a time.

Now, `getElementsByClassName` returns a "live node list", which is one that re-scans the document every time you interact with it to ensure that your container has the most up to date set of matching elements. This can cause big drops in page performance and the need for live node lists is pretty uncommon. Instead, use the more modern `.querySelectorAll()`, which allows you to pass any valid CSS selector in and returns a static node list.

```js
// Get all the desired elements into a node list
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".test");

// Convert the node list into an Array so we can
// safely use Array methods with it
let elementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);

// Loop over the array of elements
elementsArray.forEach(function(elem){
  // Assign an event handler
  elem.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("You clicked me!");
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0";
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="test">Something</div>
<div>Something</div>
<div class="test">Something</div>
<div>Something</div>
<div class="test">Something</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `this` inside your event handler:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_inscription');

var MyFunction = function() {
   this.closest('.formulaire').style.display = 'block';
   this.style.display ='none';
}

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', MyFunction.bind(buttons[i]));
}
```